# Ubuntu 12.04 does not start GUI

Tags: grub2, kernel, 12.04, ubuntu-bug

I have just upgraded my installation of Ubuntu 12.04 beta, and now I won't start the GUI. If I go into "Previous versions of Linux" from the boot-menu I can start the old upgrade without problems.
The one that doesn't works runs kernel 3.2.0-23-generic. The one that works is running 3.2.0-22-generic.

What I'm asking is how to either fix the upgraded version, or make it disappear (at least from the listing) so I don't how to mess around in grub when I boot my computer. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! This question should instead be filed as a bug report, thanks! [Instructions here](http://askubuntu.com/questions/5121/how-do-i-report-a-bug).

Comment: "ubuntu-bug linux" is what you need to type to report this bug, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to remove an entry from boot menu
you just need to edit `/boot/grub/grub.cfg` 
remove the appropriate entry

Comment: Yes, I forgot about that. Thanks! At least I can fix it so that I don't have to mess around in GRUB every time I boot. That still does not solve the problem though; that my latest upgrade does not work.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming the `xorg.conf` file to something like `xorg.conf.backup` worked to me at the first time because the system didn't tried to load the old video setup. But in my case, I`ve had to remove the nvidia-current lib because the error still occured after some time.

Normally this file is located at `/etc/Xorg/xorg.conf`.

Comment: Rename it to what?

Comment: I just renamed it in order to not be called. So you can rename it from xorg.conf to xorg.conf.bkp or so.